# php Extract from Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the multi dimensional array as follows, called from `print_r($mArray);`. How do I print the output like the sample below?

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pamount] => Array ( [0] => 190 [1] => 190 ) [psubject] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => A ) [ptype] => Array ( [0] => Water [1] => Internet ) ) )
```

Sample

```
Subject | Type    |Amount
A       | Water   |109
A       | Internet|109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$index = 0;
foreach($array['pamount'] as $key => $value){
   echo '<span>'.$value.'</span>
         <span>'.$array['psubject'][$index].'</span>
         <span>'.$array['ptype'][$index].'</span><br>';
   $index++;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the format of that array, think it needs to be `$array[0]['pamount']`